# Removeing LDAP group

Tags: ldap

I've removed the user from the LDAP server and now I would like to remove the group however I'm not sure about the proper command for this.

The command that was used to remove the user:

```
ldapdelete uid=user,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com -W -D "cn=ldapadmin,dc=example,dc=com" -x
```

Comment: Do you really mean remove the group, or remove his membership of the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be something similar to the example below, but the exact DN name will vary to your specific system.

```
ldapdelete cn=groupname,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com -W -D "cn=ldapadmin,dc=example,dc=com" -x
```